# How do I calculate statistical power on effect size of Cox regression in R?

Tags: r

I am very sorry that this is a very general question, but my google skills are completely failing me.

I would like to plot sample size to power for each effect size (or at least 0.1) according to a Cox PH test. A colleague (now left) produced a linear model power analysis in R as a placeholder for Cox regression. There are packages out there (pwr), but none deal with Cox regression.

I need to do this in R so I can overlay the results of Cox analysis on top of this power analysis to give an indication of how accurate my results really are.

This is a screenshot of what I've been presented with and essentially what I would like to recreate without fudging it by eye.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The power is defined as the conditional probability `Pr(reject H0 | H1 is true)`. [It can be shown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(statistics)#Example) that the power for a simple one-sided *t*-test can be approximated by the following function

```
B <- function(beta, n, sd = 6) {
    sem <- sd / sqrt(n)
    1 - pnorm(1.64 - beta / sem)
}
```

Here `beta` is the effect size, and in this case corresponds to the population mean (or in the language of linear models, beta corresponds to the intercept). `n` is the sample size, and `sd` a "tunable" parameter describing the standard deviation (so the uncertainty you have in the measurements). I've chosen this value such that we (more or less) reproduce results from your figure.

We can now calculate the power `B` for different values of sample size `n` and effect size `beta`. We choose the same values as in the plot you're showing.

```
n <- c(100, 500, 2500, 10000, 50000, 250000)
beta <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0)

library(tidyverse)
outer(beta, n, B) %>%
    data.frame(row.names = beta) %>%
    setNames(n) %>%
    rownames_to_column("beta") %>%
    gather(n, power, -beta) %>%
    mutate(
        n = as.numeric(n),
        beta = factor(beta, unique(beta))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(n, power, colour = beta, group = beta)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
    scale_x_log10() +
    labs(x = "sample size (N)", y = "power (%)")
```

[image]

I leave the fine-tuning up to you. It's also straightforward to adjust this example to account for different effect sizes, sample sizes and standard deviations.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for this.